# Writing 'CONTAINS' query using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, code-formatting

Given the output of query:

```
var queryResult = from o in objects
                  where ...
                  select new 
                      {
                         FileName = o.File,
                         Size = o.Size
                      }
```

What would you consider the neatest way to detect if a file is in the queryResult?
Here is my lame try with LINQ:

```
string searchedFileName = "hello.txt";
var hitlist = from file in queryResult
              where file.FileName == searchedFileName
              select file;
var contains = hitlist.Count() > 0;
```

There must be an more elegant way to figure out the result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
string searchedFileName = "hello.txt";
var contains = queryResult.Any(file => file.FileName == searchedFileName);
```